# Pointing from a shared_ptr to a list yields memory error

Tags: c++, list, shared-ptr

I'm trying to have a `list` of `shared_ptr`'s to int. When I try to point to one of the elements on the list, if I have a `shared_ptr` to the object that will point to the element it fails.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
    A(){};
    shared_ptr<int> p;
};

int main()
{
    list<shared_ptr<int>> l;
    l.push_back(make_shared<int>(1));
    cout << "counts to shared pointer: " << l.back().use_count() << endl;

    /* This works */
    A a1;
    a1.p = l.back();
    cout << "counts: " << l.back().use_count() << endl;

    /* This does not work */
    shared_ptr<A> a2;
    a2->p = l.back();
    cout << "counts: " << l.back().use_count() << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
counts: 1
counts: 2
fish: Job 1, './l' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

Comment: Ask yourself: With `shared_ptr<A> a2;`, what `A` object does `a2` point to?

Comment: Why the extra indirection to an int? That's only making things harder for yourself.

Comment: @PepijnKramer it is a simplification of the real use case. I know that it doesn't mean anything useful in this context. Looking at the answers, it is quite obvious what is happening, I just missed seeing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> /* This does not work */
> shared_ptr<A> a2;
> a2->p = l.back();
> ```

and it's not supposed to work. `a2` is a shared pointer that does not own anything. Yet, you try to dereference it with the `->` operator. The `A` object you think `a2` owns doesn't exist! You need to make one, e.g., like you did with your `int` using `make_shared()`.

Comment: Thanks, I see that a2 has not been initialised.